# Outlook Macro's: Get user initials

Tags: outlook, contactitem

I am working on a very, very simple project which sets a followup Flag on a selected message when running a macro.

I have created this so far which works very nicely, but I want to improve it by replacing the manual input of "YA" initials and put the default profile user initials as the initials.

I have found the contactitem object, but I have no idea how to get the initials out of it to put it as a .FlagRequest

Any idea's about this?

This is currently my code: (the GetCurrentItem just returns the selected email)

```
Public Sub SetCustomFlagNormal()

Dim objMsg As Object
Set objMsg = GetCurrentItem()


With objMsg
    .MarkAsTask olMarkThisWeek
    .TaskDueDate = Now
    .FlagRequest = "YA"
    .ReminderSet = True
    .ReminderTime = Now + 2
    .Save
End With

Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides the CurrentUser property for the Namespace and Account classes. The property of the Namespace class returns the display name of the currently logged-on user as a Recipient object.

`Sub DisplayCurrentUser()
   Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
   Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
   MsgBox myNameSpace.CurrentUser
End Sub`

The property of the Account class returns a Recipient object that represents the current user identity for the account. See the [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868965(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Recipient class.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a way.

After getting to multiple website, I was able to determine that Outlook doesn't offer a way to get the user initials and that Word has to be called upon to get the initials
As office uses the same initials throughout all office applications.

I got my response on this website.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/03/18/how-can-i-retrieve-the-user-name-and-user-initials-from-microsoft-powerpoint.aspx

Hope it helps